# Java program does not work, getting two errors with .add function

Tags: java

Everything has been coded, the only thing that is stopping me from running the program is the following 2 errors in the User Interface class. There is a red squiggly line under ".add" and no matter what I do it does not disappear. Any help would be appreciated.

Errors:

The method add(BasketballStats) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (Game)   UserInterface.java

The method add(BasketballStats) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (Player) UserInterface.java

```
public class UserInterface {
        public void begin() {

    ArrayList < BasketballStats > bballstats = new ArrayList < BasketballStats > ();
    boolean finished = false;
    while (!finished) {
        int selection = showMenu ();
        switch(selection) {
        case 1: 
            bballstats.add(addPlayer());
            break;
        case 2: 
            bballstats.add(addGame());
            break;
        case 3: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Displaying Details of Player or Game Stats", null, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                for (int i = 0; i < bballstats.size(); i++) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, bballstats.get(i), "Players or Game Stats", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "There are "+bballstats.size()+" record(s) in the list", "Total records", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
            break;
        case 4: finished = true;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Program Terminated");
            break;
            default: 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "\n** Invalid Selection **\n", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

public class Player {
    //Attributes
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double jerseyNumber;
    private String mainPlayingPosition;
    private String secondaryPlayingPosition;
    private double height;
    private double weight;
    private double minutesPlayed;
    //Constructors
    public Player () {
        super ();
        firstName = null;
        lastName = null;
        jerseyNumber = 0;
        mainPlayingPosition = null;
        secondaryPlayingPosition = null;
        height = 0.0;
        weight = 0.0;
        minutesPlayed = 0.0;
    }
    public Player (double p,double or,double dr,double a,double to,double pf,double b,double s,BasketballTeam bbt,String fn,String ln, double jn,String mpp, String spp, double h, double w, double mp) {
        super ();
        firstName = fn;
        lastName = ln;
        jerseyNumber = jn;
        mainPlayingPosition = mpp;
        secondaryPlayingPosition = spp;
        height = h;
        weight = w;
        minutesPlayed = mp;
    }
    //Setters
    public void setFirstName(String fn) {
        firstName = fn;
    }
    public void setLastName(String ln) {
        lastName = ln;
    }
    public void setJerseyNumber(int jn) {
        jerseyNumber = jn;
    }
    public void setMainPlayingPosition(String mpp) {
        mainPlayingPosition = mpp;
    }
    public void setSecondaryPlayingPosition(String spp) {
        secondaryPlayingPosition = spp;
    }
    public void setHeight(double h) {
        height = h;
    }
    public void setWeight(double w) {
        weight = w;
    }
    public void setMinutesPlayed(double mp) {
        minutesPlayed = mp;
    }
    //Getters
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public double getJerseyNumber() {
        return jerseyNumber;
    }
    public String getMainPlayingPosition() {
        return mainPlayingPosition;
    }
    public String getSecondaryPlayingPosition() {
        return secondaryPlayingPosition;
    }
    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
    public double getMinutesPlayed() {
        return minutesPlayed;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player's First Name: " + firstName +
                "\n" + firstName + "'s Last Name: " + lastName +
                "\n" + firstName + " " + lastName + "'s Jersey Number: " + jerseyNumber +
                "\n" + firstName + " " + lastName + "'s Playing Position: " + mainPlayingPosition +
                "\n" + firstName + " " + lastName + "'s Secondary Playing Position: " + secondaryPlayingPosition +
                "\n" + firstName + " " + lastName + "'s Height: " + height +
                "\n" + firstName + " " + lastName + "'s Weight: " + weight +
                "\n" + firstName + " " + lastName + "'s Playing Time: " + minutesPlayed + super.toString();

    }


}

package basketball;

public class Game {
    //Attributes
        private double gameNumber;
        private String opponent, arenaLocation;
        //Constructors
        public Game () {
            super();
            gameNumber = 0;
            opponent = null;
            arenaLocation = null;
        }
        public Game (double p,double or,double dr,double a,double to,double pf,double b,double s,BasketballTeam bbt,double gn,String opp,String al) {
            super ();
            gameNumber = gn;
            opponent = opp;
            arenaLocation = al;
        }
        //Setters
        public void setGameNumber(double gn) {
            gameNumber = gn;
        }
        public void setOpponent(String opp) {
            opponent = opp;
        }
        public void setArenaLocation(String al) {
            arenaLocation = al;
        }
        //Getters
        public double getGameNumber() {
            return gameNumber;
        }
        public String getOpponent() {
            return opponent;
        }
        public String getArenaLocation() {
            return arenaLocation;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Game Number: " + gameNumber +
                    "Opponent: " + opponent +
                    "Arena: " + arenaLocation + super.toString();

        }

    }
```

Comment: You have an `ArrayList <BasketballStats>` and try to add a `Game` and a `Player` to it. How did you expect that to work?

Comment: No idea, I am kind of new to java programming, what could I do to fix the issue? Please explain as simple as you can. Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: This is homework but I have done all of the code myself, just stuck with .add and I have researched on the internet to no luck, if you @Phylogenesis or anyone can help me to resolve to this and to explain to me why this error is happening so I can learn from this and to get an understanding of it, it would be great!

Comment: You have a list of `cars` and want to insert `watermelons` and `pumpkins` inside it. Does it help understanding the problem ?

Comment: Yeah I understand, I get the point but I am just asking for some help to try and resolve the two errors so I can run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add a `Player` and `Game` to the ArrayList `bballstats`, which only accepts variables of type `BasketballStats`. An `ArrayList`can only store values of **one type** (`ArrayList<TypeWhichCanBeStored>`), so you will need to create separate lists for every value.

```
ArrayList <BasketballStats> bballstats = new ArrayList <BasketballStats> ();
ArrayList <Game> games = new ArrayList <Game> ();
ArrayList <Player> players = new ArrayList <Player> ();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, much appreciated. So would the following stay the same? ArrayList < BasketballStats > bballstats = new ArrayList < BasketballStats > (); but all I have to do is repeat the above code twice, so one is for Game and the other for Player or would the above code change? Just making sure I get this done right.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I added the code but the two errors are still there.

Comment: you will need to change your switch statement aswell. Change
`bballstats.add(addPlayer());` to `players.add(addPlayer());`
`bballstats.add(addGame());` to `games.add(addGame());`